# How to use "more" and less in query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple mongodb collection:

```
{ 
  "_id" : { "id" : "3CE33FCC-AFB1-F59A-2839-3D151DB95A6B" }, 
  "value" : { "count" : 2 } 
}
```

Why this query

```
db.testb.find({ "value" : { "count" : { $gt: 1 } } })
```

doesn't work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dot notation to access sub documents in mongoDB
This should work:

```
db.testb.find({ "value.count" : { $gt: 1 } });
```

Answer (score 1):

In mongodb there is so known [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29), that can be used to reach into objects and arrays.
Workable query according to dot notation will looks like this:

```
db.testb.find({ "value.count" : { $gt: 1 } })
```